Light Rail Travel from SEA to Amtrak King Street
The goal is to be on-time for this Friday 9:55AM Amtrak Departure at Seattle's King Street Station. Assume an arrival time at the train station of 9:15.   I have to return a rental car at the Seattle airport and intend to ride the light rail.
Unfortunately, the rental car location is not the standard location, but is at:
3000 South 176th St, Seatac, WA 98188
What time do I need to be on the light rail to make it to the train station by 9:15?
If you have actual experience, please indicate as such in your answer.  Thank you

What day of the week? I'm assuming transit schedules may differ on the weekends or a holiday. The light rail runs every 20 minutes on the Sunday versus 8 minutes on the Monday that I checked.

@mkennedy Good Question: this Friday.  Thanks for asking

@gatorback Did you make it OK?

@Midavalo.  Yes.   I'm California dreaming on the Coast Starlight

We did something similar last year - had a rental car around Seattle and had to return it at SeaTac.  Ours was returned to the rental car center, so different location to you, but there was transport from the rental car center to the light-rail station.
A quick look at google maps suggests your rental car return is right next to (or across the road from) the light-rail station, about a 6 min walk.

During weekdays the wait isn't long, less than 10 minutes, and the trip to King St Station takes about 40-50 mins (actually might be quicker, according to google transit screenshot below).  The rail cars can get quite full with commuters and students, but seats were easy to find when boarding at the airport.
Since you're traveling on a weekday there shouldn't be too long a wait to find a train.  If you're concerned just go earlier and catch an earlier train into the city.  We allowed about an hour, so would have arrived before 8:15am to get to the city by 9:15am.  Probably would have aimed for 8am-ish to give a bit of wait time etc.
These are the times that Google Maps gives me for light-rail from SeaTac to King St Station (to arrive by 9:15am Friday)

I can't remember but I think there was a short walk (<5 mins) from the light-rail to the Amtrak once arriving at King Street Station.
See also Sound Transit Trip Planner with approximate details input.
